The author says it is clear that $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i-1}\neq 0$. But it is not clear for me. ("Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
The author says it is clear that $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i-1}\neq 0$.
But for me it is not clear.

Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space.
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ complex matrix.
Let $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_s$ be the distinct eigenvalues of $A$.
Let $\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}:=\{x : x\in \mathbb{C}^n, (A-\alpha_i E)^lx=0\text{ for some }l\}$.
Let $A^{(i)}$ be the $n_i'\times n_i'$ matrix with respect to some basis of a linear transformation of $\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}$ induced by $A$.
Let $\phi_A(x)=(x-\alpha_1)^{\nu_1}\cdot\cdots\cdot(x-\alpha_s)^{\nu_s}$ be the minimal polynomial of $A$.
Then, $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i}=0$ and $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i-1}\neq 0$.

I proved the above fact as follows, but I am not sure if my proof of $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i-1}\neq 0$ is okay or not.
Let $\phi_i(x):=\frac{\phi_A(x)}{(x-\alpha_i)^{\nu_i}}$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,s\}$.
Then, $\phi_1(x),\dots,\phi_s(x)$ do not have a common factor.
So, there exist $M_1(x),\dots,M_s(x)$ such that $$M_1(x)\phi_1(x)+\cdots+M_s(x)\phi_s(x)=1.$$
Substituting the matrix $A$ for the variable $x$, one has $$M_1(A)\phi_1(A)+\cdots+M_s(A)\phi_s(A)=I_n.$$
Let $A_i:=M_i(A)\phi_i(A)$.
Then, $$A_1+\cdots+A_s=I_n.$$
Further, we have $$A_iA_j=0\text{ for }i\neq j.$$
Indeed, if $i\neq j$, $\phi_i(x)\phi_j(x)$ is divisible by $\phi_A(x)$.
Therefore $\phi_i(A)\phi_j(A)=0$.
Hence $A_iA_j=M_i(A)\phi_i(A)M_j(A)\phi_j(A)=M_i(A)M_j(A)\phi_i(A)\phi_j(A)=0$.
And $A_i=A_iI_n=A_i(A_1+\cdots+A_i+\cdots+A_s)=A_i^2$.
That is, $A_i$ is an idempotent matrix: $$A_i^2=A_i.$$
From these, $\mathbb{C}^n$ can be decomosed into the direct sum of the subspaces $$A_i\mathbb{C}^n=\{x:x\in\mathbb{C}^n,A_xx=x\}.$$
Now, $A_i\mathbb{C}^n$ coincides with $\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}$.
Indeed, since $(x-\alpha_i)^{\nu_i}\phi_i(x)=\phi_A(x)$, one has $(A-\alpha_iI_n)^{\nu_i}\phi_i(A)=0$.
Hence $0=M_i(A)(A-\alpha_iI_n)^{\nu_i}\phi_i(A)=(A-\alpha_iI_n)^{\nu_i}M_i(A)\phi_i(A)=(A-\alpha_iI_n)^{\nu_i}A_i$.
This implies $A_i\mathbb{C}^n\subset\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}$.
Conversely, if $x\in\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}$, we have $(A-\alpha_iI_n)^lx=0$ for some $l$.
Since $(x-\alpha_i)^l$ and $M_i(x)\phi_i(x)$ do not have a common factor, there exist polynomials $M(x)$ and $N(x)$ such that $$M(x)(x-\alpha_i)^l+N(x)M_i(x)\phi_i(x)=1.$$
This implies $$M(A)(A-\alpha_iI_n)^l+N(A)A_i=I_n.$$
Applying this to $x$, $N(A)A_ix=x$.
Thus $x=A_i(N(A)x)\in A_i\mathbb{C}^n$.
Therefore $\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}\subset A_i\mathbb{C}^n$.
From the above, we know $$\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}:=\{x : x\in \mathbb{C}^n, (A-\alpha_i E)^{\nu_i}x=0\}.$$
So, $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i}=0$.
Since $$M_1(x)\phi_1(x)+\cdots+M_s(x)\phi_s(x)=1,$$
$x-\alpha_i$ does not divide $M_i(x)$.
So, $\phi_A(x)$ does not divide $(x-\alpha_i)^{\nu_i-1}M_i(x)\phi_i(x)$.
So, $(A-\alpha_iI_n)^{\nu_i-1}A_i\neq 0$.
So, $A_i\mathbb{C}^n$ is not a subset of $\{x : x\in \mathbb{C}^n, (A-\alpha_i E)^{\nu_i-1}x=0\}$.
Therefoere $\{x : x\in \mathbb{C}^n, (A-\alpha_i E)^{\nu_i-1}x=0\}\subsetneq\tilde{W_{\alpha_i}}$.
So, $(A^{(i)}-\alpha I_{n_i'})^{\nu_i-1}\neq 0$.
